# HTML Input type file doesn't display file name in chrome

Tags: html, jquery-ui, google-chrome, jquery-ui-dialog, file-io

I am using a `jqueryui dialog` to display a modal window which has a form with input tag of type file.

In chrome, when a file is selected, the `file name is not displayed`. When I `hover` over the browse button the name of the file is displayed but otherwise nothing. It works fine with firefox. Following is the screenshot of the issue.

[image: Chrome error]

I wanna know what should I do to display the name by the side of the choose button.

Comment: Presumably it's obvious to you, but what's your question? You never actually ask one. What do you actually want?

Comment: Can you specify which version of Chrome and jQuery UI you are using?  This appears to work fine as it stands now.

Comment: @Selosindis latest version in both. As u said, a stand alone works fine but with my app it fails. Actually this window is called from a flex component and it exists over the flex ui.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this issue as well.  To deal with it I added a field next to the browse button and then added the text on change like this:

```
   $("#fileUpload").change(function (e) {
        var path = this.value;
        this.form.field.value = "..." + path.substring(11, path.length);
   });
```

the substring was added as it was adding \fakepath\ to the start of the path name.

Comment: Any idea what causes this issue?

Comment: This was decided to be the default behavior for webkit browsers like chrome and safari. They don't have textbox like field but instead just show the text. So fixes like this must be made.

Answer (score 0):

This works well.

```
 <input type="file" class="button" id="fileupload" value="Upload file"  multiple onChange="handleFiles(this.files)">
```